# Access TinyMCE current input within iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE and I am trying to output what the user is currently typing to a div below the TinyMCE editor. I want the user to see how there post would look like rendered.

The script I am using is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#tinymce').keyup(function () {
            $('#myDIVTag').html('<b>' + $(this).val() + '</b>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have placed the corresponding div in my begin form in the view:

```
    <div id="myDIVTag">

    </div>
```

However nothing is being rendered as I type.

Comment: Fiddle would be much appreciated; quick guess is, TinyMCE editor itself is hidden within `<iframe>` element. Therefore, there's a bit more playing around to get this to work.

Comment: Yeah it is, I knew that iframe was going to make it hard. Sorry no fiddle at the moment. How can I approach this? Not sure I would be able to make a fiddle with TinyMCE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no fiddle, which makes thing harder - but it got pointed out in the comment that TinyMCE editor itself is hidden within `<iframe>` element. This seems to be the root of the issue.

To be able to access *anything* within `iframe` element with JavaScript, we must remember about Cross-Domain Policy. In short - if iframe has `src` attribute set to another domain, and website under this source doesn't explicitly let us access its contents within `iframe` - we won't be able to do it, end of the story. More: http://blog.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/ .

Luckily, I'm pretty sure it won't be of any problem here - unless TinyMCE within our `iframe` gets served from another domain.

Given all that, here's the snippet that should do the trick. Please alter selectors for your needs (I pointed them out with comments):

```
$('iframe') // iframe element
  .contents()
  .find('textarea') // textarea/other input *within* iframe
  .keyup(function () {
    $('#myDIVTag').html('<b>' + $(this).val() + '</b>');
  });
```

EDIT:

It got suggested in the comment (thanks @charlietfl!) that the proper way to approach this problem is to use TinyMCE API event, not generic binding to `textarea` element within `iframe`. Here's a quick answer taking that into account:

HTML:

```
<textarea id="tinymce-textarea"></textarea>
<div class="text-mirror"></div>
```

JS:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#tinymce-textarea",
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('change', function (e) {
      var newVal = tinymce.get('tinymce-textarea').getContent();
      $('.text-mirror').html(newVal);
    });
  }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c1zncmt8/1/ .

Basically: we're binding to TinyMCE editor "change" event, and whenever it gets triggered we get value of our input (`var newVal = ...`) and put it into separate div (`.text-mirror`).

Comment: this isn;t the correct approach because when user is typeing in WYSIWYG mode they aren't typing in a textarea. The proper approach is use the event  handling and getData() methods in tinyMCE API itself. The API exposes all that is needed

Comment: @charlietfl can you post an answer with an example

Comment: @KirstyWhite I haven't used tinyMCE for a while and really don't feel like going through the docs...but here's a start to access the `change` http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:event.tinymce.Editor.change  Then do  a search for `getData` or `getContent()` or whatever name they use

Comment: @charlietfl: I'm not really intimate with TinyMCE in any way, that's perhaps why I didn't even take such solution into account. After a bit of googling I updated the answer with your approach, including fiddle demonstrating it - thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Actually, for my purposes, your initial answer **`$('iframe').contents().find('textarea')`** was a life-saver. Did the trick, and then some. +1