# tinymce with mvc no selector name called tinymce-textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I can't seem to get the output that my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882961/access-tinymce-current-input-within-iframe) is getting for TinyMCE.
I am using MVC and my HTML razor-view looks like below.

The `TextAreaFor` is my TinyMCE. When looking at the HTML in the browser I don't see an area for `#tinymce-textarea`? So I am not sure how to bind my script to it.

All I am trying to do is output the tinymce text area to a div below it.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
      tinymce.init({
      selector: "#tinymce-textarea",
      setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function (e) {
            var newVal = tinymce.get('tinymce-textarea').getContent();
          $('.text-mirror').html(newVal);
        });
      }
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Post", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>

        <br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="text-mirror">

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation [selector](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:selector) option 'enables you to specify a CSS selector expression that will be used to find textareas you want to convert.'
In your html you don't have any textarea with id `tinymce-textarea`. All you need is add this id to your textartea html attributes

```
...
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new {Id = "tinymce-textarea"})
```

Or you can use id that is standard generated by MVC textarea helper which in your case is `Description`:

```
...
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#Description",
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('change', function (e) {
        var newVal = tinymce.get('Description').getContent();
      $('.text-mirror').html(newVal);
    });
  }
});
```